# How to find usages of implicit conversion in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit

How can I find usages of a given implicit conversion in Scala ? For example [this](https://github.com/suzaku-io/diode/blob/4f4058c6970253a78f96eb5c8b60d879cef5714c/diode-core/shared/src/main/scala/diode/ActionHandler.scala#L108). I think that there is no easy way to find them, but I am not sure. I tried InteliJ's "find usages" feature but it does not work for implicits.

Comment: There is `-Xlog-implicit-conversions`, though you'd need to trudge through tons of potential output.

Comment: You could try the age of technique of removing the conversion and seeing where things break. :)

Comment: @Alec Removing it would not give you all usages if there is another implicit definition that it can fall back to.